# Singleton object gets set for some reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, key-value, nsobject

I've got a singleton class named MyManager which holds multiple of properties. One of these properties is a custom class I've made that inherits from NSObject and also holds multiple properties.

One of my ViewControllers changes one of the properties in the MyManager class but for some reason, it also changes a property (with the same name), but inside the custom object.

To explain:

**MyManager:**

- Custom object

  - objectThatGetsSet (inside custom object)
- objectThatGetsSet

Once I set the objectThatGetsSet in MyManager, it also get's set inside the custom object. **Why is this and how can I avoid it?**

Here's the MyManager header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "myClass.h"

@interface MyManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *objectThatGetsSet;
@property (nonatmoc, strong) myClass *customObject;

+(id)sharedManager;

@end
```

And here's the implementation file:

```
#import "MyManager.h"

@implementation MyManager

@synthesize objectThatGetsSet, customObject;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods;

+ (id)sharedManager {
static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedMyManager;
}

-(id)init {
if (self == [super init]) {
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Here's the custom class header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) myClass objectThatGetsSet;

@end
```

And the implementation file:

```
#import "WorkLocationModel.h"

@implementation WorkLocationModel

-(id)init {
// Init self
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    // Setup
}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
[coder encodeObject:self.objectThatGetsSet forKey:@"objectThatGetsSet"];
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
self = [super init];
if (self)
self.objectThatGetsSet = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"objectThatGetsSet"];
return self;
}

@end
```

Please help me with this, thanks a lot!

Comment: One or the other @property should likely be `copy` and not `strong` so that you get a copy of the object and not a pointer.  With the caveat that I haven't found the code that causes what you describe.

Comment: I see, interesting, could you please elaborate this a little more? Also, I set some breakpoints on the property declaration in the MyManager class, but how can I find the "source" of the code that actually changed that declared object?

Comment: The property is type myClass*, so if you alloc one myClass instance, both myClass properties can easily point to the same instance.   For NSLogging, you can override either or both setters as long as you reimplement the assignment of the myClass* to the ivar.

Comment: I see what you ment in the first sentence but I don't quite get the second sentence

Comment: With property synthesis, each property gets an associated setter and getter method that you can override, with the caveat that when you override them, you have to implement them.   Beyond that it's a google topic.

Comment: @stevesliva ok, I think I got it. But which of them was going to be Copy and not strong? - and why?

Comment: @stevesliva also, I've made quite a big app now - just how recommended is it to use custom getters and setters? I can't like recreate my whole app for that by now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73003/discussion-between-erik-and-stevesliva).

Comment: @stevesliva finally found the glitch!;) I created a new custom object and assigned it to the one in sharedManager, ultimately giving it the same address and instance, changing both when I only intended to change one